# Using Mercurial for my website. User/group issues on server

Tags: php, apache, mercurial

I'm trying to implement Mercurial to use to manage my personal websites. Here's my current setup...

- I have a repository on Bitbucket
- I cloned the repo to my home PC for development
- I cloned the repo to my web server (Hostgator VPS) for deployment

My problem is that I can only execute "hg pull" (or any other commands) on the web as the root user. I can't su or sudo to the actual user on the web server that the account belongs to.

As a result, all files are created on my server with the user/group as 'root', and the server throws an internal server error when trying to load those files. I can use 'chown' to change the user/group on the files, and get them working. However, doing an 'hg pull' fails to copy down the changed files. It seems as though it won't overwrite the files after the owner has been changed.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually handled using a group and the group sticky bit.

For example create a group 'dev' and add both 'root' (really, they make you login as root?!) and 'apache' (where apache may actually by wwwrun or www, etc) to it:

```
% groupadd dev
% usermod --add-to-group dev root
% usermod --add-to-group dev apache
```

Then chgrp all the files over to that group:

```
% chgrp -R dev /path/to/repos
```

Then make sure all group members can read and write those file:

```
% chmod -R g+rwx /path/to/repos
```

The make sure any newly created files are automatically in that group:

```
% find /path/to/repos -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s
```

Then any new files created by apache will be owned by the 'dev' group which both it and root can read.  Root will need to make sure the files it creates from the command line had read/write permissions for group too.

**Note:** Doing anything like this with root is unsafe -- use a dedicated account whenever possible, I always create 'hg'.

This is explained [here in the Mercurial wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MultipleCommitters).